# Conversion from HSI to RGB

Tags: matlab, rgb

I'm converting an image HSI to RGB. I'm using this code:

```
X=imread("C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\MLBS_1.tif");
H=inpict(:,:,1);
S=inpict(:,:,2);
I=inpict(:,:,3);
H=H-360*floor(H/360);
a=H<120;
b=H<240 & ~a;
c=~a & ~b;
R=zeros(size(H));
G=zeros(size(H));
B=zeros(size(H));
B(a)=I(a).*(1-S(a));
R(a)=I(a).*(1+S(a).*cos(H(a).*(pi/180))./cos((60-H(a))*(pi/180)));
G(a)=3*I(a)-R(a)-B(a);
H(b)=H(b)-120;
R(b)=I(b).*(1-S(b));
G(b)=I(b).*(1+S(b).*cos(H(b).*(pi/180))./cos((60-H(b))*(pi/180)));
B(b)=3*I(b)-R(b)-G(b);
H(c)=H(c)-240;
G(c)=I(c).*(1-S(c));
B(c)=I(c).*(1+S(c).*cos(H(c).*(pi/180))./cos((60-H(c))*(pi/180)));
R(c)=3*I(c)-G(c)-B(c);
outpict=cat(3,R,G,B);
imshow(uint8(image));
```

However, this error is thrown:

```
Undefined function 'cos' for input arguments of type 'int16'
    Error in hsi2rgb (line 13)
R(a)=I(a).*(1+S(a).*cos(H(a).*(pi/180))./cos((60-H(a))*(pi/180)));
```

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: That is not the full error. Please post the error text, the one that tells you why is failing.

Comment: Undefined function 'cos' for input arguments of type 'int16'.

Error in hsi2rgb (line 13)
R(a)=I(a).*(1+S(a).*cos(H(a).*(pi/180))./cos((60-H(a))*(pi/180)));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loaded image is `int16`, i.e. its not float. You want to work with floating points. Convert your image into a floating point image using `X=double(X)`

I suspect you are expecting values between 0-360 for H, S and I. You need to first make sure that your image is in this range, and if not, normalize it. `int16` `.tif`s can have values up to `65536`, and I suspect that would break your conversion a lot.